# Using streams to find an object in a list of lists

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to write a method that finds the indices of an object in a list of lists and takes advantage of parallelism. Here is my code.

```
// returns [i, j] where lists.get(i).get(j) equals o, or null if o is not present.
public static int[] indices(List<? extends List<?>> lists, Object o) {
    return IntStream.range(0, lists.size())
                    .boxed()
                    .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(0, lists.get(i).size()).mapToObj(j -> new int[]{i, j}))
                    .parallel()
                    .filter(a -> {
                        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));     // For testing only
                        return Objects.equals(o, lists.get(a[0]).get(a[1]));
                    })
                    .findAny()
                    .orElse(null);
}
```

When I run the following code

```
List<List<String>> lists = Arrays.asList(
        Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"),
        Arrays.asList("D", "E", "F", "G"),
        Arrays.asList("H", "I"),
        Collections.nCopies(5, "J")
);
System.out.println("Indices are " + Arrays.toString(indices(lists, "J")));
```

the output is something like

```
[0, 0]
[0, 1]
[0, 2]
[3, 0]
[3, 1]
[3, 2]
[3, 3]
[2, 0]
[3, 4]
[1, 0]
[1, 1]
[2, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
Indices are [3, 0]
```

In other words, the search continues even after the object has been found. Isn't `findAny` supposed to be a short-circuiting operation? What am I missing? Also, what is the best way to take advantage of parallelism when iterating over a list of lists or a jagged array?

**EDIT**

Following the idea in @Sotirios's answer, I got an output of

```
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3,5,main] [3, 0]
Thread[main,5,main] [2, 0]
Thread[main,5,main] [2, 1]
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1,5,main] [1, 0]
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1,5,main] [1, 1]
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1,5,main] [1, 2]
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1,5,main] [1, 3]
Thread[main,5,main] [0, 0]
Thread[main,5,main] [0, 1]
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3,5,main] [3, 1]
Thread[main,5,main] [0, 2]
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3,5,main] [3, 2]
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3,5,main] [3, 3]
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3,5,main] [3, 4]
Indices are [3, 0]
```

Notice that

```
Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3,5,main]
```

continues searching even after the answer is found.

Comment: use findFirst() instead.

Comment: @TaharBakir It still continues searching.

Comment: Also, parallelism may take some time before one thread can notify the others that they don't need to keep going.

Comment: @LouisWasserman  When I print the thread as in Sotirios's answer, I find that even within the same thread, the search continues after the object is found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short-circuiting operations do not guarantee to only pull as few elements as it takes to produce their result.  They *may* do so, but it is not required.

The current implementation of `flatMap` is such that it will always push the substream's entire contents downstream.  So even if your stream weren't parallel, you could see more elements flow through the stream than it takes to satisfy `findAny`.

Comment: It appears that this answer is right, and that `flatMap().filter().findAny()` is basically not short-circuiting. I don't know why it would be implemented this way.

Comment: "short-cuircuiting" merely means that it *may* terminate before examining the entire stream.  It doesn't make any guarantees beyond that.

Answer (score 2):

As for "why it was implemented this way". The problem lies deeply in the Stream API implementation. The `flatMap` body often creates a stream with some intermediate operations (like `.flatMap(list -> list.stream().map(...).filter(...))`). One could use inside the `flatMap` implementation `stream.spliterator()` and call `tryAdvance` many times until the cancellation is requested. However the `spliterator()` call returns somewhat artificial spliterator when the stream contains intermediate operations (if not, it just returns the original stream spliterator). This artificial spliterator has not very efficient [tryAdvance()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/StreamSpliterators.java#StreamSpliterators.WrappingSpliterator.tryAdvance%28java.util.function.Consumer%29) implementation, so using this implementation might be considered as worse performance drawback compared to consuming the whole flatMapped stream. In many cases you flatMap to some short streams, so here you may have a performance gain thanks to the current implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that it continues, it's that it has already dispatched all sorts of threads to try and find the result and will wait until those have completed before returning the result.

In other words, the `findAny` terminal operation will submit the "search" task to a number of threads. These tasks are simply applying the `filter` `Predicate` and returning when something returns `true`. `findAny`, presumably, waits for one of these to return a value. There's no way for it to really cancel anything it has already submitted and it seems this implementation will block until the entire batch returns. It can only stop submitting any future batches.

You can verify this by logging the current thread:

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " " + Arrays.toString(a)); // For testing only
```

Comment: I'm half asleep, so this is probably a stupid question, but if a load of worker threads are given tasks up front, and the whole method cannot return until they all finish, what does short-circuiting even mean?

Comment: @PaulBoddington I don't think it's _all_, I think it's some subset.

Comment: @PaulBoddington For example, I fire off 5 threads to search. All 5 might return a result. But I have to wait for all 5 before I can decide. (Well you really only have to wait for one, but you can't cancel the others. And this implementation seems to want to join on all those 5 tasks.)

Comment: @PaulBoddington I think that's a consequence of the `flatMap` as Misha states. I gotta run for my bus, brb.